# Firebase Cloud Messaging (WebPush) token expiration handling

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

As I found out in [Firebase source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/fcb277a832058407a33456b2887a6b9990708b28/packages/messaging/src/controllers/controller-interface.ts#L129), every token has an expiration time of one week. And because `messaging().onTokenRefresh` is [not implemented now](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/fcb277a832058407a33456b2887a6b9990708b28/packages/messaging/src/controllers/window-controller.ts#L43), I'm assuming that there is no way of sending webpush-notifications to users that haven't been on my website with configured FCM for a week or longer.

Or my assumption is incorrect and this expiration exists only on browser side? And tokens on the server-side of FCM aren't expiring without a call from browser to recreate token?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an actual expiration, but just a way to update the token information on Firebase servers. If the token is still valid (and it most likely is), `updateToken` method will return the same token, and it will keep working.

If you get a different token after a `getToken` call, you can safely overwrite the previous token in your server.