# FCM Token Expiration

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any possibility to regenerate a new push token while the app is running in the background?

I have an app that runs on background for a long time which depends on the push messages to trigger some function. In some cases, the user might not close the app but keep running in the background in offline mode for days. This can be But when I'm testing it's experienced that sometimes push token on the server has expired.

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onNewToken(java.lang.String)) they haven't mentioned anything specific on when will this token get refreshed. (OnNewToken method gonna trigger)

What might be the issue? Any idea would be a great help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079039/firebase-cloud-messaging-webpush-token-expiration-handling

Comment: this is what you need probably : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193215/firebase-cloud-messaging-handling-logout